# Dynamically create angular object with key, value from angular.forEach()

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
    if ($scope.data) {
        $formData = [];
        angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key){

            console.log(key);  //  o/p: 'fruitname'
            var k = key;
            var value = value || 'Not Available';
            console.log(value); // o/p: 'apple'

            var parts = {k : value};
            console.log(parts);  // o/p: Object {k: "apple"}
            $formData.push(parts);
        });
    }
```

Why i cannot able to populate key, while creating parts object. or how can i do the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need to do is `parts[k] = value;`
Actually when you assign parts = { k : value }; , This goes something like this :

```
parts["k"] = value;
```

So you see instead of taking the value of k, it takes k as string and assign a value to this string as key field.

Comment: yeah...  i got it..  i change my code as parts[key] = value; and it is working now.  Thank you

Answer (score 2):

it works when i try to do like this.

```
if ($scope.data) {
    $formData = [];
    angular.forEach($scope.data, function(value, key){

        console.log(key);  //  o/p: 'fruitname'
        var value = value || 'Not Available';
        console.log(value); // o/p: 'apple'

        var parts = {};
        parts[key] = value;
        console.log(parts);  // o/p: Object {"fruitname": "apple"}
        $formData.push(parts);
    });
}
```